# Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive

I would like to create a function like;

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION func AS 'pathTo/TrackToCsvExtractor';
```

This is the returning message of adding jar file.

```
Added /mnt/var/lib/hive_0110/downloaded_resources/TrackToCsvExtractor.jar to class path
Added resource: /mnt/var/lib/hive_0110/downloaded_resources/TrackToCsvExtractor.jar
```

And, i am facing an error

```
FAILED: Class pathTo/TrackToCsvExtractor not found
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask
```

All the class files are correct and although i have been adding the jar file and whenever i do

```
list jars;
```

It does lists me the jar file that i have added.
I am totally out of ideas and wondering why do i facing this error.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer on my own,
I had to compile the jar files with all the classes and etc with everything instead of just the class that I would use.

Comment: u can't just down vote my answer, i just  have improved and answered in appropriate manner, so that  it is easy to understand and helpful to everyone @Ducaz035

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using the function inside settings while running a query, turns out there was a hidden space. when typing the function's classpath be sure there are no leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score -3):

You have to compile the `<class name>.java` file before building the jar. out of it

To compile

```
javac <class name.java>
```

Build a Jar out of it

```
jar cvf <jar_fileName>.jar <class_name>.class
```